# Rxjs, fromEvent handle multiple events

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to combine multiple events `blur` and `keyup (enter key only)` using `fromEvent`. I have implemented blur event, how I can combine keyup.enter as well.

I have tried with the `filter` operator but with the filter, enter is working onblur is not -

**Component.ts**

```
this.propertyDescription.forEach((input: ElementRef) => {
    const events = ['blur', 'keyup'];
    from(events)
    .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$),
        mergeMap((event) =>
            fromEvent(input.nativeElement, event)
        ),
        filter((e: KeyboardEvent) => e.key === 'Enter'),
        map((evt: any) => evt.target.value),
        distinctUntilChanged(
            (pre: any, curr: any) =>
                JSON.stringify(pre) === JSON.stringify(curr)
            )
        )
        .subscribe((caption: string) => {
            console.log(caption);
        });
});
```

Comment: Your filter doesn't work because you are only taking events where `e.key === 'Enter'`. If you want it get keyup you need to expand that. I like the other suggestions here though. View filter like you would an `if` statement for each event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing now is sending "blur" and "keyup" to your main observable.

What you need to do is declare what the "keyup" event does, what the "blur" event does and the apply your logic.

Something more like:

```js
this.propertyDescription.forEach((input: ElementRef) => {
  const blurEvent$ = fromEvent(input.nativeElement, 'blur').pipe(/* your logic for "blur" event */);
  const keyupEvent$ = fromEvent(input.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(/* your logic for "keyup" event */);
  merge(blurEvent$, keyupEvent$).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$),
    /* rest of your logic */
  )
  .subscribe();
}
```

---

*Edit:* merge does not take an array.
see on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-j8scn5?file=index.ts)

Comment: after subscribing I am getting `Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}`. Is there any way to get the value directly from subscribe?

Answer (score 4):

1. Subscription inside a `forEach` is an inelegant design. It'd lead to multiple (potentially unhandled) subscriptions. You could use `merge` with `Array#map`.
2. Also instead of using `from` you could use `merge` with multiple `fromEvent`s.

Try the following

```js
const events = ['blur', 'keyup'];

merge(
  this.propertyDescription.map((input: ElementRef) =>
    merge(
      events.map((event: string) => 
        fromEvent(input.nativeElement, event).pipe(
          map((evt: any) => evt.target.value),
          distinctUntilChanged((pre: any, curr: any) =>
            JSON.stringify(pre) === JSON.stringify(curr)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
).pipe(
  takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
).subscribe((caption: string) => {
  console.log(caption);
});
```

Comment: getting this error - `Type 'Observable<Observable<any>>' is not assignable to type 'string'`

Answer (score 1):

better way to do it in angular would be to send events from template

```
<input #inp (keyup.enter)="valueUpdates$.next(inp.value)" (blur)="valueUpdates$.next(inp.value)">


//ts
valueUpdates$ = new Subject<string>();


this.valueUpdates$
  .pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe((caption: string) => console.log(caption));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to listen to changes that have been made after leaving the input element (`blur`) or after the user clicked Enter, you could just use the `change` event instead.

However, if there is some reason you explicitly want to use `blur` and `keyup` with Enter, you have to fix your `filter` operator. Right now, you're filtering out all Events that have no `key` property with the value 'Enter'. The `FocusEvent` `blur` doesn't have that property, so the filter function returns `false`.

A working filter should look something like this:

```js
filter((e: KeyboardEvent | FocusEvent) => e instanceof FocusEvent || e.key === 'Enter'),
```